# nodejs passing in the end point of the url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a simple js app to query a cassandra db like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver')
var app = express();
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], keyspace: 'custprd'});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello Ronak!');
});

app.get('/customer/:ent_cust_id', function (req, res, next) {
        var query = 'Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?';
        consolelog('Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?');
        client.execute(query, [req.params.ent_cust_id], function (err, result) {
    if (err) return next (err);
    var row = result.rows[0];
    //Response
    res.json({ent_cust_id: req.params.ent_cust_id, name: row.get('offers')});
});
});


var server = app.listen(3030, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

now, when I go an type the call `http://10.205.116.141:3030/customer/1013686356` in the web browser, I get this back:

```
Error: Expected 4 or 0 byte int (10)
```

and the console log is showing this:

```
Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?
```

I thought the `?` was the way to pass in the end point of the url?

EDIT:

I think this has to do with execute vs executeAsPrepared...I use executeAsPrepare, I get this error: 
`TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

so here is how I got it to work:

```
app.get('/customer/:ent_cust_id', function (req, res, next) {
        var query = 'Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?' [req.params.ent_cust_id];
        consolelog('Select * from entcustinfo where ent_cust_id = ?');
        client.execute(query, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return next (err);
    var row = result.rows[0];
    //Response
    res.json({ent_cust_id: req.params.ent_cust_id, name: row.get('offers')});
});
});
```

I moved `[req.params.ent_cust_id]` up to `var query`